# How can I check what permissions an app store app will request before installing it?

Tags: ios, security, ios-appstore

I would like to find out, prior to installation, what permissions an iOS app will ask for.

I understand that *granting* these permissions is up to me and that no permissions are granted automatically.  However, my decision to install an app *at all* is very much influenced by how over-reaching the permission requests are going to be.

So, without actually installing the iOS app, how can I look up the app and see what permissions it will ask to use ?

I believe the google play store allows you to check this on the play store itself, prior to downloading - how can I do this in the app store ?

Answer (score 2):

The iOS App Store does not display the permissions the app will request.  You can view certain info about an app prior to downloading:

- Seller
- Size
- Category
- Compatibility
- Languages
- Age Rating
- In-App Purchases
- Copyright
- Developer Website (link)
- Privacy Policy (link)

Unless the developer indicates the required permissions in their app description, Privacy Policy or Website, you will not know until the app requests that permission.

Comment: That is surprising and disappointing.  Can I really not download the actual app file itself and open/inspect it in xcode and get some idea of what it does ?  Or do we really need a third party review mechanism where people actually install and use the apps and publicize (potential) permission abuses ?

Comment: No, you can't download the app file from the iOS App Store.  It's installed automatically when it's downloaded.